# How to edit responses when I'm the only user of the form?

Tags: google-forms

I use a simple google form with just 2 dropdowns each day, to track certain work activities and what the result of each one was.  I'm the sole user/owner of this form.

Over time, I have refined the names of many of the options on the form.  However the summary pie charts, don't update to reflect my changes so there are numerous slices of pies that don't actually exist, and belong to other slices.

Google claims that form responses are editable, but I can't do it.  I have the setting to edit responses enabled (always was), and I understand that Google does not allow the form owner to edit responses from other people.  But all responses were also submitted by me.  Can I not edit my own responses?

I was not sending response URLs as I didn't realize I would need to, and it would result in multiple URLs being sent every day which would quickly become unmanageable.

Is there a way to edit the responses that the summary charts are pulling from?  Or am I stuck manually generating my own charts no a new sheet if I want such summaries?

Comment: If you don't have the emails with the edit response URL, you have to use a script to get them.

Comment: So even though I'm the only user, I'm going to have to get every individual response URL and figure out which are the ones I want to change?  If so... not worth the effort and I'll just have to make my own pie charts.  Thanks anyway.